# Write code segment that prints out the sequence of all hour and minute combinations of the day starting with 4:00A.M. and ending with 12:59 AM

Tags: java, while-loop

Use while loops only.

Can I get hints? 
I don't know what "sequence of all hour and minute combinations of the day" means.
Does it mean a continuously printing timestamp with the hour and minute at each interval?

This is what I tried. Can you help me with my errors?

```
 int hours = 4;
    int minutes = 0;

    TimePrinter(minutes, hours);

    while (hours<=12)
    {
        while ( hours<=12 &&minutes<=59)
        {
            TimePrinter(minutes,hours);
            minutes++;

            while (hours<= 12 && minutes== 60)
            {

                minutes = 0;
                 hours++;
                TimePrinter(minutes,hours);

            }
        }
    }

}

private static void TimePrinter(int minutes, int hours) {
    if (hours <12 && minutes<10)
    {System.out.println(hours + ":0" + minutes );}
    else
    {System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this mean sequence

```
00:00
00:01
...
00:59
01:00
....
23:58
23:59
```

I don't remember C syntax good, but I will try

```
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;

while(hours <= 23) {
  while(minutes <= 59) {
    printf("%02d:%02d\n", hours, minutes);
    minutes++;
  }
  hours++;
  minutes = 0
}
```

UPD: I'm sorry Only now view that you need Java. I think I can understand my idea and code.

Comment: @newman  I wrote code as seen in the updated question but I have some errors. can you please help me spot them?

Comment: @newman sorry, I forgot to add that this program prints the sequence of numbers starting with 1:00A.M. and ending with 12:59 AM.

Comment: @AmandaKelius just set init value for hours to 1 and change condition in first while to `hours <=12`

Comment: @newman To convert to Java, you'd just change `printf` to `System.out.printf`

Comment: @Compass thank you. I know it. But this is studies task and I think will better if Amanda fix this self ;)